# In cygwin Python script print with sleep not printing output

Tags: cygwin

I am using cygwin to run a python script which use a while loop and `time.sleep()` to display an output. If I exclude `time.sleep()` from inside of loop, cygwin terminal display the output as expected. When I use `time.sleep()` function it don't show any output.

```
import time
while True:
      print "hello world"
```

This example is working without `time.sleep()`

```
import time
while True:
    print "hello world"
    time.sleep(1)
```

This code don't display any output in cygwin terminal.

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue with Python 2.7.14 on an up-to-date installation of Cygwin (64-bit) running on top of Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks, I am also using python2.7 in Windows 10 64-bit installation.

Comment: Perhaps it depends on the type of terminal emulator, which python is not recognising. Try running python with option `-u` for unbuffered output.